# Custom Citation with Optional Second argument

Tags: macros, citing

I would like my command `citat` to give the citations author followed by the citations document in parenthesis and optionally any other arguments to go with the document year. I have tried the following

```
\newcommand{\citeat}[2]{\citeauthor{#1} (\citeyear[#2]{#1})}
```

So that in my main document I can call something like

```
\citeat[p. 92]{Harris1979}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you'd want a new command, because you get the behavior with the standard command `\citet` (of `natbib`).

Anyway, I add a definition for your `\citeat` command. The `filecontents` environment is just to make the example self-contained.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{test,
 author={A. Uthor},
 title={Title},
 journal={Journal},
 year=2017,
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}

\newcommand{\citeat}[2][]{%
  \citeauthor{#2}%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    ~(\citeyear{#2})%
  \else
    ~(\citeyear[#1]{#2})%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}
\raggedright

No optional argument: \citeat{test}

Optional argument: \citeat[p.~92]{test}

Standard without optional argument: \citet{test}

Standard with optional argument: \citet[p.~92]{test}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `biblatex`, the standard command `\textcite` does what you want.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{test,
 author={A. Uthor},
 title={Title},
 journal={Journal},
 year=2017,
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\raggedright

Standard without optional argument: \textcite{test}

Standard with optional argument: \textcite[92]{test}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I use `\RequirePackage{biblatex}`.

Comment: @Jordan It's the same: the macro `\textcite` already does what you want.

Comment: Since `biblatex` can automatically add the `p.~`/`pp.~` itself, `\textcite[92]{test}` is preferred over `\textcite[p.~92]{test}` with `biblatex`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

```
 \newcommand{\citeat}[2][ ]{ \citeauthor{#2} (\citeyear[#1]{#2}) }
```